# What is the best practice when switching jobs

Tags: job-offer, new-job, resignation, job-change, contracts

I recently accepted a job offer (a week ago) while I still had two other interviews that were in the last stages of getting me hired.

Because I needed a job badly, I accepted the first offer that came. They are really happy about having me as part of their team because I have started showing good signs.

A week after starting the work I got offers from the other two jobs I was interviewing for, with each offering way better salary and better working conditions as well.

I need to make a decision about what to do now. What do I need to consider when I make this decision?

Comment: Hi Beatrice, I've edited your question, as questions about what to do are usually closed on this site. Please revert or change my edit if you don't agree with how I've rephrased your question.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: I get the sense that this is someone very early in their career. Do you feel it's that large of a concern early on? It's absolutely a concern for an established career, and I'd be interested in your thoughts on if that kind of reputation hit is really all that impactful early on.

Answer (score 3):

**This isn't something we can answer for you - because ultimately, it comes down to you having to decide what sort of employee/person you are.**

The company you've accepted a job at?  They've made plans and have sunk costs into bringing you on board and training you.  If you leave now, they're going to have to start that process all over again.  The people involved in your hiring will have a negative association with you, and that might filter through their friends/acquaintances.  Does that matter to you?  This isn't a leading question, or saying whether it *should* matter to you.  But it's a value judgement that *you* have to make.

There are people here that would say, "The company will look out for it's own interest, and you should look after yours - if you get a better offer, jump ship."  Others would say, "It's a poor way to repay a company to quit after a week - despite that company not actually doing a single thing wrong by you."  And both of them have their points - it's all about personal choices on the people making them.